# Python process killed

Tags: python-2.7

I am running the following code and I receive a 'killed' message from python:

```
import random,string

def rotations(t):
        ''' Return list of rotations of input string t '''
        tt = t * 2
        return [ tt[i:i+len(t)] for i in xrange(0, len(t)) ]
def bwtViaBwm(t):
        return ''.join(map(lambda x: x[-1], bwm(t)))
def bwm(t):
        return sorted(rotations(t))

def build_FM(fname):
        stream=readfile(fname)
        fc=[x[0] for x in bwtViaBwm(stream)]


def readfile(sd):
    s=""
    with open(sd,'r') as myfile:
        s =myfile.read()
    return s.rstrip('\n')

def writefile(sd,N):
        with open(sd, "wb") as sink:
            sink.write(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in xrange(int(N))))
            sink.write('$')
        return
def main():
    fname= sys.argv[1]
    N =sys.argv[2]
    writefile(fname,N)
    build_FM(fname)
    return

if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
```

It takes as input a file name and a number. The code creates a random stream of size `N` and then runs the BWT transformation on that stream. When I give as input `N=500000`, I am getting a 'killed' message, which seems a small number for memory error. My system runs Ubuntu 14.04, 8GB RAM and python 2.7.

This is how i run the script:

```
python  fm.py new_file.csv 500000
```

and i am getting this after some seconds:

```
killed
```

Comment: You should include the specific error!

Comment: how am i getting that? The console just outputs killed

Comment: Can you print the exact console input/output you're getting? Note that we don't know how you're invoking your program, or what *specifically* the console is reporting: unfortunately without this we can't replicate your problem.

Comment: @NathanielFord i changed the question with that info

Comment: My system's RAM gets filled up in 3 seconds, then the process is killed.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a memory issue: my system also overloaded and shut it down.

Comment: But it sounds weird. It is just a stream of 500000 chars! It cannot be processed by modern PCs?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with your `rotations` function:

```
def rotations(t):
    ''' Return list of rotations of input string t '''
    tt = t * 2
    return [ tt[i:i+len(t)] for i in xrange(0, len(t)) ]
```

Looking at what it does:

```
>>> rotations('x')
['x']
>>> rotations('xx')
['xx', 'xx']
>>> rotations('xxxxx')
['xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx']
```

The result of this will expand exponentially. Thus, a file of `500000` characters will produce a result of length `500000^2`.

Computationally, there is unlikely to be a way to do what you're attempting for an input that large: which is to get every rotation of a string 500k characters long. We know that there is one output for each element in the input, and each output has a length of the original input. Thus, the minimum size is `n*n` or `n^2`. Unless you know you need only a limited number of these (and can cull them early), you are always going to run into a problem with this.

**How to fix the problem**

First we need to identify the problem. Lets look at what the code is doing. Suppose a simple starting set:

bacb

`rotation()` provides all the possible rotations of that set:

```
>>> rotations('bacb')
['bacb', 'acbb', 'cbba', 'bbac']
```

You then sort this list.

```
>>> sorted(rotations('bacb'))
['acbb', 'bacb', 'bbac', 'cbba']
```

And then you take the last element of each, yielding `bdac`. What this translates to is that for each element `n` in your input, you are assigning a sort order such `n+1 ... n` (wrapping around) would be sorted alphanumerically.

To solve that, then, the algorithm will be:

- create an empty list 'final_order', which will be a list of 'sorted' indexes of the input list.
- For each element

  - get the 'rotation' of the original string starting at that element plus one
  - place in a sorted way that rotation into a 'final_order' list:
  - Get the 'rotation' of the first element of the 'final_order' list.
  - Compare the two rotations.
  - If the new rotation is less than the old rotation, insert into the list at that point. Otherwise go to the next rotation.
  - If no additional rotations, place the new rotation there.

(There is probably a faster way to sort, but I'm going with this for ease of explanation.)

The first thing we need is `get_rotation(input, idx)`:

```
def get_rotation(input, idx):
    return input[idx + 1:] + input[:idx + 1]
```

Now the hard part (see comments):

```
def strange_sort(input):
    sorted_indices = list()  # Initialize the list

    for idx in range(len(input)):  # For each element in the list
        new_rotation = get_rotation(input, idx)  # Get the rotation starting at that index
        found_location = False  # Need this to handle the sorting
        for sorted_idx in range(len(sorted_indices)):  # Iterate through all 'found' indices
            old_rotation = get_rotation(input, sorted_indices[sorted_idx])  # Get the rotation starting at the found/old rotation
            if new_rotation < old_rotation:  # Which comes first?
                # If this one, insert the new rotation's starting index before the index of the already sorted rotation
                sorted_indices.insert(sorted_idx, idx)
                found_location = True
                break
        if not found_location:  # If greater than everything, insert at end
            sorted_indices.insert(len(sorted_indices), idx)
    return "".join(map(lambda x: input[x], sorted_indices))  # Join and return result
```

Running this we get an expected result on a short input:

```
>>> print("Final result={}".format(strange_sort('bacb')))
Final result=bbca
```

This is the full program with test/timer:

```
import random, string, datetime

def get_rotation(input, idx):
    return input[idx + 1:] + input[:idx + 1]

def strange_sort(input):
    sorted_indices = list()

    for idx in range(len(input)):
        new_rotation = get_rotation(input, idx)
        found_location = False
        for sorted_idx in range(len(sorted_indices)):
            old_rotation = get_rotation(input, sorted_indices[sorted_idx])
            if new_rotation < old_rotation:
                sorted_indices.insert(sorted_idx, idx)
                found_location = True
                break
        if not found_location:
            sorted_indices.insert(len(sorted_indices), idx)
    return "".join(map(lambda x: input[x], sorted_indices))

n1 = 5
n2 = 50
n3 = 500
n4 = 5000
n5 = 50000
n6 = 500000

n = [n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6]

def test(lst):
    for l in range(len(lst)):
        input = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits) for x in range(lst[l]))
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        result = strange_sort(input)
        end = datetime.datetime.now()
        runtime = end - start
        print("n{} runtime={} head={} tail={}".format(l, runtime.seconds, result[:5], result[-5:]))

test(n)
```

The attempt is to take advantage of not needing to store everything, just store the index of the final sort for each index of the initial sort. Sadly, the above implementation is clearly too slow, as we can see from running it:

```
$ python2 strange_sort.py
n0 runtime=0 head=SJP29 tail=SJP29
n1 runtime=0 head=5KXB4 tail=59WAK
n2 runtime=0 head=JWO54 tail=7PH60
n3 runtime=4 head=Y2X2O tail=MFUGK
(Still running)
```

Ok, so we knew the sort was awful. Can we make it faster? We see from the [Python Wiki Entry on Big-O](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) that it takes `O(M)` to take a string slice. This, for us, means `O(N)` because we are taking two slices that add to the full length. This is computationally a disaster, because we're doing it every time.

Rather than get the full rotation each time, lets iterate and compare. A single comparison of one index of one rotation to one index of another rotation should be `O(2)`. In the worst case we have to do this `O(N)` times, but it is unlikely that will be the case every time.

We add an additional for loop and rework it to only be looking at the next index:

```
for offset in range(len(input)):
    if new_rotation[offset] < input[(sorted_indices[sorted_idx] + offset) % len(input)]:
        sorted_indices.insert(sorted_idx, idx)
        found_location = True
        break
if found_location:
    break
```

We now execute it with our timer:

```
$ python2 strange_sort.py
n0 runtime=0 head=VA6KY tail=VA6KY
n1 runtime=0 head=YZ39U tail=63V0O
n2 runtime=0 head=JFYKP tail=8EB2S
n3 runtime=0 head=IR4J9 tail=VLR4Z
n4 runtime=28 head=EYKVG tail=7Q3NM
n5 runtime=4372 head=JX4KS tail=6GZ6K
```

As we can see, we made it to `n4` this time in only 28 seconds. This doesn't bode well for `n6`, though. Alas, it looks like the computational complexity of this suggests that we need a better method of *sorting* than [Insertion Sort](http://bigocheatsheet.com/), which at it's worst (and even average) is `O(n^2)`. On input of `500K` that will take `250B` (billion) calculations at a minimum. (Times `n`, the number of actual instructions done by the computer per calculation).

What we *have* learned is that you don't actually require writing aside the rotations. To solve this problem you have to write a fast sorting algorithm that takes as it's input not an actual value, but a function that can calculate the value at a given degree of precision.

Turning the entire thing on it's head, I thought about trying to create an object that could search far enough into itself to know how it sorts against another object, and use the built-in sorting of Python.

```
import random, string, datetime
from functools import total_ordering


@total_ordering
class Rotation(object):
    """Describes a rotation of an input based on getting the original and then offsetting it."""

    def __init__(self, original, idx):
        self.original = original
        self.idx = idx

    def getOffset(self, offset):
        return self.original[(self.idx + offset) % len(self.original)]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        print("checking equality")
        if self.idx == other.idx:
            return True
        for offset in range(len(self.original)):
            if self.getOffset(offset) is not other.getOffset(offset):
                print("this={} is not that={}".format(self.getOffset(offset), other.getOffset(
                        offset)))
                return False
        return True

    def __lt__(self, other):
        for offset in range(len(self.original)):
            if self.getOffset(offset) < other.getOffset(offset):
                return True
            elif self.getOffset(offset) > other.getOffset(offset):
                return False
        return False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.getOffset(-1)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "".join(map(lambda x: str(x), [self.getOffset(idx) for idx in range(len(
                self.original))]))


def improved_strange_sort(input):
    original = list(input)
    rotations = [Rotation(original, idx) for idx in range(len(original))]
    result = sorted(rotations)
    # print("original={} rotations={} result={}".format(original, rotations, result))
    return "".join(map(lambda x: str(x), result))


def test(input):
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    result = improved_strange_sort(input)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    runtime = end - start
    print("input={} runtime={} head={} tail={}".format(input[:5], runtime.seconds, result[:5],
                                                       result[-5:]))


def timed_test(lst):
    for l in range(len(lst)):
        print("Test {} with length={}".format(l, lst[l]))
        test(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(lst[l])))


n1 = 5
n2 = 50
n3 = 500
n4 = 5000
n5 = 50000
n6 = 500000

n = [n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6]

test('bacb')
timed_test(n)
```

And this seems to produce correct results:

```
$ python2 strange_sort.py 
input=bacb runtime=0 head=bbca tail=bbca
Test 0 with length=5
input=FB2EH runtime=0 head=BF2HE tail=BF2HE
Test 1 with length=50
input=JT3ZP runtime=0 head=W8XQE tail=QRUC3
Test 2 with length=500
input=TL8L7 runtime=0 head=R4ZUG tail=M268H
Test 3 with length=5000
input=PYFED runtime=1 head=L5J0T tail=HBSMV
Test 4 with length=50000
input=C6TR8 runtime=254 head=74IIZ tail=U69JG
Test 5 with length=500000
(still running)
```

Comment: Is there a better alorithmic solution?

Comment: @curious Provided as much as is feasible. I might update again if my slow-sort version eventually completes. I estimate that it would take this algorithm 3.5 days, though.

Comment: Thanks!Where this final extra loop should go in the final code?

Comment: Beneath `for sorted_idx in range(len(sorted_indices)):`. But see my update.

Comment: @curious Be sure to upvote/accept answers that helped you! This will help with getting more, quality, help in the future!

Comment: Actually the problem is that when i create the matrix, or the list in which each element is 500000 long, i don't need all the characters of that, i only need the first one from each element of the list and the last one. Is there a way to optimize based on that?

Comment: @curious Unless you mis-stated the problem, that isn't actually true. Consider a string with repeated characters: `accb`: with just the first character the rotation `ccba` would sort before `cbac`, resulting in a last-character order of `a` then `c` instead of vice versa. Repeated characters means you *have* to look at more precision.

Comment: You did not understand what i said: Have a look at slide 16 http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~langmea/resources/lecture_notes/bwt_and_fm_index.pdf

Comment: So i only need the first and the last column! That is the first and the last character of each element in the lest created by the rotations algorithm

Comment: @curious aye, you need only the first and last character. However, according to your documentation you need to sort the strings first, and only after you can pick your characters. Or are both Nathaniel Ford and I misunderstanding it?

Answer (score 1):

I did some experiments, the problem resides in `rotations(t)`.

The first problem is that you are doubling the size of the input string, which initially is 500.000 characters and becomes 1.000.000. But that would be still affordable, we are still talking of 1.5 megabytes or so of memory.

But after that you create a list of 500.000 strings, each one 500.000 characters long, which is approximatively the equivalent of `232 GB` of memory that are required to just float around for the next computation step to occur.

That's obviously impossible since none of us has so much RAM, so your program gets killed.

---

You asked whether it's possible to `optimize` this code.. .. I take it for `is it possible to employ less memory?`

Let's say that you're willing to trade computational time in exchange for less memory consumption, then you **could** write a version of the algorithm which doesn't require so much memory. For example:

```
def bwtManual(t):
    tt = 2 * t
    res_str = ''
    old_min = None
    for j in xrange(0, len(t)):
        cur_min = None
        print("Round: " + str(j))
        for i in xrange(0, len(t)):
            # generate 1 string at a time
            tmp_str = tt[i:i+len(t)]
            # select an initial minimum string
            # > must not be smaller than previous minimum
            if cur_min is None:
                if old_min is not None:
                    if tmp_str > old_min:
                        cur_min = tmp_str
                    else:
                        continue
                else:
                    cur_min = tmp_str
                continue
            # skip strings that have been already selected
            if old_min is not None and tmp_str <= old_min:
                continue
            # select new minimum among remaining strings
            if (tmp_str < cur_min):
                cur_min = tmp_str
        # store character
        res_str += cur_min[-1]
        old_min = cur_min
    return res_str
```

On small sizes, no problem, just a bit slow.

On 500.000 characters? it would take **115 days** on my machine, which has average computational power.

---

**to wrap up:**

The strings that are generated from `rotations(t)` really don't have any reason to exist on their own.. these strings exist only for allowing us to execute `sort()` and then extrapolate the last character of each string.

Is it possible to do better than this? I think yes.

The idea would be to design your own sorting function that uses references to sub-strings of  `tt` instead of copies of it. So you would need only a couple of pointers for each **rotation** instead of a full copy of the original string.

I've tried to look for hints on doing this in python, and I found the objects `memoryview` and `buffer` which looked very promising. However, apparently these wrappers don't seem to implement the comparison operators natively, and require you to extrapolate (a copy of) the string they are pointing to. This would defeat the entire purpose of using these wrappers in your context, so probably they won't be of much use. You can look them up and decide for your own.

I think that it would be much easier to design a C++ module that sorts abstract nodes referencing sub-string of the original string, and then returns the final string that you build with your `map()` code. Then you could connect this module to your python code, or simply write the rest of the code in C++ as well.

Comment: I updated my answer according to your additional question, I hope it helps.

Comment: Actually i only need the first and the last character of each rotation, not the intermediate chars. That is the first and last matrix if we see the returned list of 500.000 characters as a matrix. Will that allow further optimization? I am trying to see if i can delete intermediate chars

Comment: AFAIK You can't, you need the whole bunch of strings in order to sort them. As i said the only optimization you can do is by tweaking the code so to not need so much memory, and that will speed it up quite a bit in practice, but your complexity will remain lower bounded by that of your sorting algorithm.